# select uncommon rows based on single column in MSSQL or LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql, sql-query-store

I want to select a API_PATH which is not common between ADMIN and SUPER ADMIN role.

```
╔════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ API_ID ║      API_PATH       ║  ROLE_NAME  ║
╠════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║      1 ║ /objects/Types      ║ Super Admin ║
║      2 ║ /objects/Types      ║ Admin       ║
║      3 ║ /organization/list  ║ Super Admin ║
║      4 ║ /objects/Types/6498 ║ Super Admin ║
║      5 ║ /objects/Types/6498 ║ Admin       ║
╚════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The desired result should be:

```
╔════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ API_ID ║      API_PATH      ║  ROLE_NAME  ║
╠════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║      3 ║ /organization/list ║ Super Admin ║
╚════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

In the above **/organization/list** is only API_PATH which is not common in both roles, I need to select API_PATH utilizing ROLE_NAME. How can i do it using MSSQL or LINQ without hardcoded?

Comment: does 'common' in your wording mean a hard coded string like '/objects/Types' or is this completely dynamic?

Comment: to be completely specific: in all 5 rows the sequence '/o' is equal

Comment: I need to select API_PATH which are not common between 2 roles

Comment: BTW, without hardcoded what?

Comment: Without hardcoding ROLE_NAME or API_PATH

Answer (score 0):

if you add a constant string it should be super simple like:

```
SELECT 
    API_ID, 
    API_PATH, 
    ROLE_NAME 
FROM #Results
WHERE 
    API_PATH NOT LIKE '/objects/Types1%'
    AND API_PATH NOT LIKE '/objects/Types2%'
    AND API_PATH NOT LIKE '/objects/Types3%'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I cannot hardcode as i have thousands of API_PATH and having multiple ROLE_NAME

Comment: i do not have a solution for this. See my updated answer. But i guess that is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
SELECT 
    API_PATH 
FROM #Results
GROUP BY API_PATH
HAVING COUNT(API_PATH) = 1
```

with a result of:

[image]

Comment: I can see the ouput, but the issue is my ROLES are dynamic i need to include roles in the query as i have multiple roles

Comment: @vijaymadishetti A simple `WHERE` should handle that...?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Roles` (`List<string>`) contains the roles you want to group by, then this should work:

```
var ans = db.Where(d => Roles.Contains(d.ROLE_NAME))
            .GroupBy(d => d.API_PATH)
            .Where(dg => dg.Count() == Roles.Count)
            .SelectMany(dg => dg);
```

Depending on the version of LINQ to SQL/EF/EF Core, you may need an `AsEnumerable` after the `Where`, which will pull all rows containing the desired `Roles` across. Unfortunately, in e.g. EF Core 3.1, there is no translation for complicated `GroupBy` expressions (and in this case, there isn't a great SQL translation regardless).

This seems to work with EF Core 3.1 at the (possible) expense of filtering twice on the SQL side:

```
var paths = db.Select(d => d.API_PATH)
              .Distinct()
              .Where(p => db.Where(d => Roles.Contains(d.ROLE_NAME) && d.API_PATH == p).Count() < Roles.Count);
var ans = db.Where(d => paths.Contains(d.API_PATH) && Roles.Contains(d.ROLE_NAME));
```